# AngularJS ng-repeat not working with DatePicker controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can't seem to get the inlined calendar button associated with the DatePicker to work using ng-repeat on two DatePickers.  They both work when I instantiate the DatePickers separately, but I wanted to try and use ng-repeat.  I want to be able to associate the two DatePicker fields so when you fill out "Date From" it will set the min date of "Date To".  I put an example together of the buttons not working or calling open() properly, not sure how to do the rest yet, still very new to AngularJS.

http://plnkr.co/edit/EPg0fmZN7YdVsvhiRgBa

Thanks

Comment: Sorry no, I gave up on it :(